# Fourier Transform Sin & Cos

Tags: fourier-transform

I would like to calculate the fourier transform of cos(wt) by taking the derivative of the fourier transform of sin(wt).

We know that $\boldsymbol{F}(\dot{x})=jw\boldsymbol{F}(x)$ -->

$\boldsymbol{F}(cos(w_{o}t))=\boldsymbol{F}(\dot{\frac{1}{w_{o}}sin(w_{o}t))}=\frac{1}{w_{o}}\boldsymbol{F}(\dot{sin(w_{o}t)})=\frac{1}{w_{o}}jw\boldsymbol{F}(sin(w_{o}t))=\\\frac{1}{w_{o}}jw*\frac{1}{2j}(\delta (w-w_{o})-\delta (w+w_{o}))=\frac{w}{2w_{o}}(\delta (w-w_{o})-\delta (w+w_{o}))$

since $\delta (w-w_{o})-\delta (w+w_{o})$ is non-zero only at $w=\pm w_{o}$ ; $\boldsymbol{F}(cos(w_{o}t))$ turns out to be

$\boldsymbol{F}(cos(w_{o}t)) = \frac{1}{2}(\delta (w-w_{o})-\delta (w+w_{o}))$

However we know that $\boldsymbol{F}(cos(w_{o}t)) = \frac{1}{2}(\delta (w-w_{o})+\delta (w+w_{o}))$

I could not figure out the mistake I am doing in my derivation. Can you please point out my mistake?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}(\cos(\omega_0 t))&=\frac{1}{\omega_0}\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{d\sin(\omega_0 t)}{dt}\right)\\\\
&=-i\frac{\omega}{\omega_0} \mathscr{F}(\sin(\omega_0 t))\\\\
&=\left(-i\frac{\omega}{\omega_0} \right)\frac{1}{2i}(\delta(\omega +\omega_0)-\delta(\omega -\omega_0))\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\delta(\omega +\omega_0)+\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\delta(\omega -\omega_0)\right) \tag 1\\\\
&=\frac12 (\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+\delta(\omega-\omega_0)) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we exploited the property that $f(x)\delta(x-x_0)=f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)$.

Applied here, we note that for the term $-\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\delta(\omega +\omega_0)$, the Dirac Delta is "active" when $\omega=-\omega_0$.  Therefore, at $\omega=-\omega_0$, $-\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}=+1$.

Comment: Hi Dr.MV, thanks for the answer but why did you put minus sign in the second line, ie. should not be it $i\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}$ instead of $-i\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}$ ?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I am using $e^{i\omega t}$ as the kernel in the Fourier Transform.  Perhaps you are using $e^{-j\omega t}$.  This difference will not affect the result.

Comment: Now I got it, I forget to use minus sign while calculating the equation at w=-w_0. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  Pleased to hear that you have it now!!  -Mark

Comment: I will Dr.MV but for the second line I am still not sure. If you are using  $e^{j\omega t}$ as the kernel, then I believe the sign must be positive: i.e. $x(t)=\int e^{jwt}X(w)dt$, then $\dot{x(t)}=\int jw*e^{jwt}X(w)dt=jw\int e^{jwt}X(w)dt=jwX(w)$. Let me know if there is a mistake here.

Comment: The second line is fine.  You wrote the inverse FT for $x(t)$, for which the kernel is $e^{-i\omega t}$ as I am defining it.

Answer (score 0):

you got it right until the end, in fact $\frac{1}{2}(\delta (w-w_{o})+\delta (w+w_{o}))=\frac{w}{2w_{o}}(\delta (w-w_{o})-\delta (w+w_{o}))$